# Mac Codesign wants wrong key

Tags: macos, certificate, codesign

I am trying to publish an iPhone app on my Mac. When building the application, it asks me:

"codesign wants to sign using key "Ryan Rasmussen" in your keychain."

I think that Ryan Rasmussen is my key for my computer.

I think it is supposed to use one of the keys that I installed from iTunes connect for those users.

So when I use Application loader to try to upload the app, it doesn't like the certificate.

How do I get codesign to use the correct certificate?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your AppStore build is picking up a development certificate. Make sure that your Release target is set to `iOS Distribution`.

If that doesn't fix the problem, you can explicitly select the correct distribution certificate in the same setting.

If you don't see the distribution certificate in the Code signing identity dropdown menu, check that the certificate is available in `Keychain Access.app`. If it isn't there, you need to double click the certificate in the finder to import it.

Comment: yes the problem was I was trying to use a development provisioning profile. They don't work. I am now using the app store distribution profiles and they also work with test flight. Ad Hoc profiles don't work with test flight. Also, it is normal for it to ask you if the key can be accessed, with it saying your name.